# Why getting NaN on redux while adding a number

Tags: javascript, redux

I am learning redux. I am trying to learn redux by increment decrementing value. I have written a code. While I am dispatching `INCREMENT_BY_VALUE` it is showing `NaN` But `INCREMENT`, `DECREMENT` and `RESET` are working properly.

Here is my code:

```
const { createStore } = require("redux")

const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT'
const DECREMENT = 'DECREMENT'
const RESET = 'RESET'
const INCREMENT_BY_VALUE = "INCREMENT_BY_VALUE"

const initialCounterState = {
  count: 0
}

const incrementCounter = () => {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT
  }
}

const decrementCounter = () => {
  return {
    type: DECREMENT
  }
}

const incrementByValue = (value) => {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT_BY_VALUE,
    action: value
  }
}

const resetCounter = () => {
  return {
    type: RESET
  }
}

const counterReducer = (state = initialCounterState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1
      }

    case DECREMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count - 1
      }

      
    case RESET:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: 0
      }

    case INCREMENT_BY_VALUE:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + action.payload
      }

    default:
      break;
  }
}

const store = createStore(counterReducer)

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
})

store.dispatch(incrementCounter())
store.dispatch(decrementCounter())
store.dispatch(resetCounter())
store.dispatch(incrementByValue(10))
```

I am getting this output form my code:

```
{ count: 1 }
{ count: 0 }
{ count: 0 }
{ count: NaN }
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix that?

Comment: What is `action.payload` It's not defined anywhere, thus you are calculating `somevalue + undefined` which is `NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `incrementByValue` action creator returns an object with an `action` property, but in the reducer function, you are accessing the `payload` property, which does not exist. That is evaluated to `undefined` and adding that to a number results in `NaN`.

Either change the reducer to use the `action` property or make the action creator return an object with the `payload` property.